# Simplifying Logs

Tags: logarithms

Simplify: $$\frac{\log a + \log b - \log c}{\log d^2}$$

Using the basic properties of logs, the numerator should simplify to $\log (ab/c)$, if I'm not mistaken. The denominator $\log d^2 = 2 \log d$ but I don't know where to go from there. Can it be further simplified?

Comment: you can go any farther; answer is $\frac{\log(ab/c)}{2\log d}.$

Comment: Eh. You could do change of base, but arguably that makes it worse.

Comment: So the best answer here is probably just the simplification of the numerator as described above?

Answer (score 1):

You may further simplify this to:  $log_d \sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}$
As Jgon suggested.

Comment: How exactly does that work, I don't understand ?

Comment: $log{a}/log{b}=log_b{a}$  I leave it to you to prove. Good exercise for practice.

Comment: I understand this now, but how do you turn the d^2 into the square root of ab/c ?

Comment: Don't square the d, use the 2 that you get from $logd^2 =2logd$ to divide the numerator..